# row alignment is incorrect in table

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table where at first row there is a background image and some content over it. The second row of the table should start from below the first row but it is appearing at top of the first row.

Have tried properties like display, break and other things for new line

```html
<html>

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <style type="text/css">
    .bg-image {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      background-image: url(./Images/Home.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
      -moz-filter: blur(2px);
      -o-filter: blur(2px);
      -ms-filter: blur(2px);
      filter: blur(2px);
    }
    /* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
    
    .bg-text {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      /* Fallback color */
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
      position: absolute;
      top: 60%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 2;
      width: 95%;
      height: 40%;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: White; max-width: 100%; overflow-y:  
     auto;">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="bg-image">
          </div>
          <div class="bg-text">
            Welcome to CoachX
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <h1 style="font-variant: normal; font-family: Times New 
            Roman; font-size: 5em; color: Black;">
          This is not visible</h1>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

The second row (This is not visible) of the table should appear below to the first row but it is appearing above the first row

Comment: i'm not seeing any row: https://jsfiddle.net/wj2sLy08/1/

Comment: why you are combining table and div tags, you can achieve this purely using div tags using css '-webkit-order' and 'order'. z-index is not for ordering tags, z-index is for layering one above another, also your position fixed and position absolute combination is also needs to be re-visited

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Bootstrap(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)
In your case:

```
<div class="container">

   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">

    <form>
            <h1>This is not visible</h1>
    </form>


      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
          Table down
      </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: hi, welcome to stack overflow, kindly advise without table tags, that would be really great